# JIRA in IFrame portlet - javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, liferay, jira

I'm attempting to embed a JIRA application into Liferay as an IFrame portlet. I can successfully navigate to the JIRA site and login, but after that none of the Javascript elements work. So I can't use any of the drop-down menus, and even the JIRA fields themselves don't display properly.

I should also mention that the Liferay & JIRA apps are being hosted by the same Tomcat server.

Can anyone think of a reason this would be happening?

Thanks!
Carleen

EDIT: Upon finally running Firebug I see I'm getting the following error: "Permission denied to access property BLAH". Why would this happen when Liferay and JIRA are being hosted from the same server??

Answer (score 0):

This is still concidered [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and at the same time it doesn't violate the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

However there is a standards-compliant way of course :)

You can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't quite understand. At what time would I call window.postMessage? I'm not doing anything with the source code of either application - just deploying their respective war files in Tomcat.

Comment: I was a bit afraid of that. window.postMessage is a mechanism for such communication that is used to achieve it so that both "parties" are shure that the request is not a forgery. You should ask Atlassian on this one over at [answers.atlassian.net](http://answers.atlassian.net/)

Comment: Thanks, I did. No one really has a solution there either. *sigh* I can't believe I'm the first Liferay user to deal with this.

Comment: @user1660256 it is very strange that Atlassian doesn't know anything about that. You can file a support enquiry with them so that they solve it for you. Since you're a customer you've hot support from them. [support.atlassian.net](http://support.atlassian.net/) Just register and you're in! Also please accept this answer if it was helpfull to you.